# No module named "data_utils"...But it is downloaded

Tags: python, scipy, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

So, I was having the simple error,

> "No module named "data_utils"

when trying to import it into a python program.  So I thought it must not have downloaded and spent like 20 mins trying to ensure a proper download.  Turns out it was fine all along and the `data_utils.py` file is in the utils folder.

I'm really stuck because I see it right there, yet it simply won't import.  I looked for a .bin after the `__init__.py` files but it seems like they are fine.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: whats your project directory structure? post it in the question

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused by what you mean by that.  I'm new to using python libraries.

Comment: no worries man, here is an example, reproduce this for your files: https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=990&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=directory+structure+ascii+diagram&oq=directory+structure+ascii+diagram&gs_l=img.3...24510.31603.0.31834.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.0.0.0ENzR36kWtM#imgrc=8xM2vMcmUlJR2M:

Comment: Maybe thats where I'm going wrong.  I have my main .py project file, and all the dependencies are scattered around in different folders.  Do they have to be allocated to one place.  Or am I just confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deducing from your comment the answer would be:

The files have to be in the same directory /and some sub-directory for an import like `import data_utils` to work.

There are some way to get around this but to start try to keep it simple at first.

for example:

given a directory structure like this:

```
| --main.py
| --data_utils.py
| --train.py
```

and suppose you have a function `remove_punctuation` in data_utils:

you could use import that with:

```
from data_utils import remove_punctuation
```

or you could import all the functions (and or classes in data_utils) with:

```
from data_utils import *
```

or you can import data_utils with

```
import data_utils

# use remove_punctuation
data_utils.remove punctuation
```

The directory structure could also be:

```
|--main.py
|--bar
   |--foo
|--src
   |--train.py
```

and you could import remove_punctuation using

the same semantics as above qualifying the directory using dot notation:

```
from bar.foo import foo
```

**EDIT: would module import like scipy have to be in the same directory?**

**Short answer** 
*no*

**Long answer**:

When you install `scipy` and `numpy` etc (packages you install from pip or using the sudo) they add themselves (their location) to the `PYTHONPATH` so you don't have to have them in the same directory as your project code.

Modules that you want to use globally must be added to your PYTHONPATH. Python searches for modules  (roughly) in the directory and sub-directory of the file it is executing and in the `PYTHONPATH`.

**if you want global import of your own modules**

I.e, if you want to use `data_utils.py` everywhere you could do assuming you are using bash on linux and assuming you have data_utils.py in a directory named `data-utils`:

add an `__init__.py` to `data-utils`, so your directory structure would look like this:

```
|--data-utils
  |--__init__.py
  |--data_utils.py
```

then add this line to your ~/.bashrc:

```
export PYTYHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/data-utils
```

`data-utils` (and by extension `data_utils.py`) is permanently added to the `PYTHONPATH` and can be imported by any project code.

Comment: Okay, this seems to make sense.  So if I had multiple programs which use the library, for example, scipy, would all those programs have to be in the same directory?  Thanks

Comment: I apologize for asking so many questions.  But do I run these commands in cmd.  I am running windows and it says that export is not a command.  However, I found a program on my computer called git bash, which has a valid export command, but I'm not sure if thats just a coincidence.  I'm also confused about what you mean by adding to the .bashrc.  I think i have heard the concept of a bashrc, but I only see one .bashrc file on my system and it is a visual studio code file.  Thanks

Comment: my advice: **dont worry about running the commands in the long answer section**. Instead add the file `data_utils.py` to the same folder as `main.py` then try `import  data_utiils.py`

Comment: So, unfortunately, I have about 200 main.py files, and about 200 __main__.py files, so which one is it?  I see many coming from Anaconda, some from pip, and some from other folders.  Any specifics I should search?

Comment: what is the name of the file your are trying to import data_utils.py?

Comment: "chsum.py" is the name of the file I am importing to.

Comment: OK, you need to put `data_utils.py` in the __same folder__ as `chsum.py` then try importing

Comment: Ahh, I feel stupid now.  When you said main.py, I thought that was literal.  My apologies, common sense is not my thing, but thank you for everything, its working perfectly! :)

Comment: Glad I can help, would be lovely if you'd accept the answer

Comment: What does data_utils exactly does  ?